# How can I fix custom Kendo UI theme CSS which causes an IE 8 glitch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui

Trying: [Kendo UI Mendu demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html) with custom theme ([Kendo UI Custom Themes](http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html) or modified theme CSS)

I've customized the Bootstrap theme, and encountered a glitch in IE 8 when mousing over a menu item, only when using the custom theme CSS.

Customized Bootstrap theme example: http://jsbin.com/ovufef/1/edit (Glitch in IE 8)

Original Bootstrap theme example: http://jsbin.com/urinev/1/edit (works as expected)

Kendo UI Menu:

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        Stores
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div style="padding: 50px;">
                    <h2>Around the Globe</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").kendoMenu();
});
</script>
```

View the CSS in the jsBins, they are too long to include here since they are Kendo themes.

Basically the glitch is when you mouse over an item, it does not drop the sub item down immediately, you must move your mouse over where the sub item would display, and wiggle around until it weirdly and magically appears.

I'm unsure what is causing the IE8 glitch in my custom theme. The styles are so simliar, I can't figure out what's causing it. I have done a file diff on the CSS, and seems to me (after looking at the diff a few times) to be only background color, gradient, border color, etc changes.

If anyone could help me fix the custom CSS, it would be much appreciated.

---

*Notes:*

- *Bootstrap is just theme name, nothing to do with Twitter Bootstrap... just looks similar.*
- *I **hate** IE with a passion, this was not my choice (and for the most part Kendo works fine in IE)*
- *jsBin used because IE8 does not work in jsFiddle*
- ***Update: viewing jSBin in new window, glitch is not produced** but does reproduce in web app with custom theme used. More research needed, will update or answer soon*

Comment: "Kendo UI Menu custom theme IE 8 glitch" That's not a question, I think it's just a list of nouns w/ one random adjective.

Comment: "I hate IE with a passion"  Welcome to IT :)

Comment: @VoidKing you are correct, it was a bunch of nouns, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bundyo was correct, the issue does not happen in the jsBin new window. However, it was still reproducing on a site I was developing. I eventually figured out it was my gradient syntax for IE most likely causing the problem.

Changed to:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#80ffffff, endColorstr=#00ffffff, GradientType=0);
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#80ffffff, endColorstr=#00ffffff, GradientType=0);
```

Originally I had `startColorstr='#80ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff'` with the single quotes, which may have been an issue.

fixed jsBin for reference: http://jsbin.com/ovufef/12/edit

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft's DirectX filters are quite broken. The opacity one for instance is known to break image and font alpha transparency in some cases (and in IE7 every time). The parser is also rather strict and it defies logic from time to time, check for instance my comment in this article:
http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=922&cpage=1#comment-1234

Answer (score 2):

Something happens in that jsBin iframe - if you open the bin in a new window - it works.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I do see it working in the new window. I thought I tried that before, and it wasn't working. Regardless, in a web app, I'm using the custom theme, still produces the glitch. So I'll have to modify the jsBin to reproduce the issue more closely. Edit or answer to come soon.